# Simple `Sum` evaluating wrong

Tags: summation

I want to make a table of values for the sum

```
Sum[\[Phi][x - i*j], {j, 1, x}, {i, 1, x}]
```

I want to include non-integer values of `x` in order to later compare it to the Abel Summation Formula. Of course, these intermediate values of `x` should produce the same output for the sum as `Floor[x]`. But they don't. For example:

```
\[Phi][x_] := x^3
table1 =
   Table[{x, Sum[\[Phi][x - i*j], {j, 1, x}, {i, 1, x}]}, 
      {x, 1, 5, 0.5}]; 
TableForm[table1, TableAlignments -> Left, 
   TableHeadings -> {None, {x, sum}}]
```

produces this:

[image]

Is this a quirk of Mathematica? What assumptions is it making? Or am I just doing something blindingly stupid?

Comment: OK, so I am being stupid! Since `x` is in the formula rather than just a limit of summation, of course it gives different values for all different `x`. I am feeling veeeery silly!

Comment: Try: `\[Phi][x_] := x^3;
f[x_] := Evaluate[Sum[\[Phi][x - i*j], {j, 1, x}, {i, 1, x}]];
table1 = Table[{x, f[x]} // N, {x, 1, 5, 1/2}];
TableForm[table1, TableAlignments -> Left, 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {x, sum}}]`

Comment: Hi @Mariusz. Can I ask why adding `Evaluate` changes the outcome? Also, is it producing the right result? Is it not the case that `Sum[\[Phi][x - i*j], {j, 1, x}, {i, 1, x}] /.x->1.5` equals 0.125? Surely, since `i=1,j=1`, we have `\[Phi][x - i*j]=\[Phi][0.5]=0.125`? What am I missing?